# How to set a cookie expiration time when login using AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am authenticating with a Custom AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public UserData authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

       return (UserData) authentication;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UserData.class);
    }
```

In order to login a user I do:

```
   UserData auth = authManager.authenticate(new UserData(loginData));
       
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

(`UserData` extends `AbstractAuthenticationToken`)

When I do this, the user gets a `JSESSIONID` with an expiration time of -1 (until browser closes).

How can I do so the JSESSIONID has a custom expiration time? Can I also renew it if the user is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authentication Provider is managed by Spring Security so the parameters of the cookie expiration time sent to the servlet work also with the custom AuthenticationProvider.

You need to set the `max-age`:

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        max-age: 30m
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concept of remember-me functionality given by spring like this :

```
      @Configuration
      @EnableWebSecurity
      public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Bean("authenticationManager")
      @Override
      public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user1").password("{noop}user1Pass").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin1").password("{noop}admin1Pass").roles("ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
        
        .and()
        .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        
        .and()
        .rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret")
        ;
}
```

}

By default the time expiration of this is 2 weeks but you can also configure that by using tokenValiditySeconds. For example you want it to expire after 1 day then:

```
    rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret").tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried that but if the coockie max-age was -1, it did nothing. I had to change that first, as I detail in my answer.